# Nested array into array, adding brackets around nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Cannot find anything on this, there is a lot of information on appending string values using push or typing out the whole array using push; but not using a nested array by the array variable name. Just need one pair of [] around my user inputed values.

```
var rows = []
var cols = []

rows after user input:

Array(4)
0: (4) ["ROW1", "ROW1", "ROW1", "ROW1"]
1: (4) ["ROW2", "ROW2", "ROW2", "ROW2"]
2: (4) ["ROW3", "ROW3", "ROW3", "ROW3"]
3: (4) ["ROW4", "ROW4", "ROW4", "ROW4"]

cols.push = ([rows])
```

Desired output is just

```
cols = [["ROW1", "ROW1", "ROW1", "ROW1"]
  ["ROW2", "ROW2", "ROW2", "ROW2"]
  ["ROW3", "ROW3", "ROW3", "ROW3"]
  ["ROW4", "ROW4", "ROW4", "ROW4"]]
```

Or this

```
cols = [["ROW1", "ROW1", "ROW1", "ROW1"],
  ["ROW2", "ROW2", "ROW2", "ROW2"],
  ["ROW3", "ROW3", "ROW3", "ROW3"],
  ["ROW4", "ROW4", "ROW4", "ROW4"]]
```

To be reproduced
I believe this is how data is represented from chrome after input

```
var rows = []
var cols = []

rows = ["ROW1", "ROW1", "ROW1", "ROW1"]
  ["ROW2", "ROW2", "ROW2", "ROW2"]
  ["ROW3", "ROW3", "ROW3", "ROW3"]
  ["ROW4", "ROW4", "ROW4", "ROW4"]

cols.push = ([rows])
```

Full Code

```
'use strict';

var items = []
var rows = []
var cols = []

function myFunction() {
    items.push(document.getElementById('itemid').value);
    items.push(document.getElementById('itemid1').value);
    items.push(document.getElementById('itemid2').value);
    items.push(document.getElementById('itemid3').value);
    console.log(items);
    const arrayToMatrix = (array, columns) => Array(Math.ceil(array.length / columns)).fill('').reduce((acc, cur, index) => {
        return [...acc, [...array].splice(index * columns, columns)]
    }, []);
    const result = arrayToMatrix(items, 4);
    var rows = result;
    console.log(rows);}

document.getElementById('my-Function').onclick = myFunction;

function exportData() {
    cols.push = ([rows]);
    console.log(cols);
    let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," 
        + rows.map(e => e.join(",")).join("\n");

    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();}

document.getElementById('export-Data').onclick = exportData;
```

Comment: In your first example, `cols` already == `rows`?

Comment: first, please show a minimal reproducible example, second, how that output is genrated?

Comment: No, I am just creating the variable cols, in order to put rows inside of it with brackets [ ]

Comment: @Berto99 it is from a chrome extension popup form

Comment: `rows` is already a 2-dimensional array. Each element is an array with brackets around it.

Comment: You can't assign `rows` like that.

Comment: I am trying to add another set of brackets, excel/csv wont read the arrays without an additional set of brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```js
var cols = [];
var rows;

rows = ["ROW1", "ROW1", "ROW1", "ROW1"];
cols.push(rows);
rows = ["ROW2", "ROW2", "ROW2", "ROW2"];
cols.push(rows);
rows = ["ROW3", "ROW3", "ROW3", "ROW3"];
cols.push(rows);
rows = ["ROW4", "ROW4", "ROW4", "ROW4"];
cols.push(rows);

console.log(cols);
```

You don't need to use `[rows]` -- `rows` is already an array, and `push()` creates the containing array.

The value of `rows` can come from user input.

```js
let cols = [];

while (true) {
  let input = prompt("Enter words, blank line or Cancel when done");
  if (!input) {
    break;
  }
  let rows = input.split(" ");
  cols.push(rows);
}
console.log(cols);
```

Comment: I am looking to put an additional bracket around rows so output looks like:[["ROW1", "ROW1", "ROW1", "ROW1"],
  ["ROW2", "ROW2", "ROW2", "ROW2"],
  ["ROW3", "ROW3", "ROW3", "ROW3"],
  ["ROW4", "ROW4", "ROW4", "ROW4"]]       CSV wont read it without an additional bracket

Comment: Did you click on "Run code snippet"? Doesn't my code do that?

Comment: Yes, I appreciate your help; however I am trying to do this without typing it all out as the user input is variable. It could have and additional array, Row 5

Comment: `rows = function_that_gets_user_input(); cols.push(rows);`

Comment: It doesn't matter how `rows` is set. Once it's set, you use `cols.push(rows)` to add it to `cols`.

Comment: I've added a second example showing how to do it using user input.

Comment: Really appreciate your help @Barmar, I will mark you the answer. I believe my code needs restructuring I have added it at the bottom just so you can see how I have my user inputting.

Comment: `var rows = result;` is assigning a local variable, not the global variable. Get rid of `var` there.

Comment: `cols.push = ([rows]);` is totally wrong. You should be calling the function, not assigning it.

Comment: Every time you click on `my-function` it replace `rows` with the current input, it doesn't add to it. So `rows` will always contain just the last set of inputs. You're not going to get a CSV file that way.

Comment: You should do `cols.push(rows)` in `myFunction`, not in `exportData()`. Also, I don't see why you need `arrayToMatrix()`. You're taking an array with 4 elements and returning an array with 4 elements. You would only need that if you had an array with more elements and you wanted to group it into a matrix.

Comment: I was using array to matrix so each row ends up being a new line in csv (two dimensional array) but the way you wrote the answer should solve that, if I added cols.push(rows) in the top function it would screw up the two dimensional array how I originally set it up. Again I believe if I use your answer that should not happen. Again thank you for your help!